# Laravel Overwrite Route::Resource to Alternate Method

Tags: http, laravel, laravel-routing

Currently working on a Laravel project. The route that I'm working with is defined as a resource, but I'd like to change the post to use UpdateTicket() instead of store(). How would I overwrite just the post route of the defined resource?

Comment: If you are updating something, you should use a *PUT* request instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would just be to call `UpdateTicket()` in `store()`

```
public function store(){
    return $this->UpdateTicket();
}
```

Comment: Would the POST variables need to get passed through if I do this?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, yes.